# using a variable in constructor in a method outside of constructor

Tags: java, methods, constructor

if i have a constructor like so:

```
    public Constructor (int a, int b){

        int c =  a;
        int d =  b; 
    }
```

How can i then use variable c and d in a method within the same class as the constructor because trying to use just the variables name in the method doesn't seem to work?

Comment: `int c = int a;` will not compile, you need `int c = a;`

Comment: after fixing what I said before, you can pass them as parameters to your methods (from within your constructor) or save the values in instance attributes and use them in the method.

Comment: not sure why this was down voted, seems like a valid question to me.

Comment: it's not [sscce](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In fact your code will not compile - `int c = int a` is not valid.

I assume that you meant: - `int c = a;`.

> How can i then use variable c and d in a method within the same class
>   as the constructor

You can't because you have declared them as local variables whose scope ends when the constructor ends execution.

You should declare them as instance variables.

```
public class MyClass {
    int c;
    int d;

    public MyClass(int a, int b){

        this.c = a;
        this.d = b; 
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(c + " : " + d);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried to fix a syntax error and got rolled back. Make sure you keep it next time you edit :)

Comment: Yeah I just removed the 2nd ints (on the right hand side of the assignment in the constructor). It looks good now.

Comment: What's the difference in that case between using this.c = a and c = a?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the variables as class members, outside the constructor. In other words, declare c and d outside of the constructor like so:

```
int c;
int d;

public Constructor (int a, int b) {

        c = a;
        d = b; 
}
```