# Getting Scanner from your Constructor to a method within the class?

Tags: java, class

Note: This is an assignment, and I am asking to be pushed in the right direction, this is also more of a question about technique rather than logic.

So I have this class called AnimalHospital, and in the Constructor takes a filename String as a parameter:

```
    public AnimalHospital(String inputFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // this is required
```

In the constructor, I read in a file that I have placed through my main, and the constructor should be able to read this file in. My issue is that I need to use the variable from the constructor that represents the scanner, in another method within the same class. This class should not have any variables, so I am unsure about what to do.

here is the AnimalHospital class:

```
  import java.util.*;
  import java.io.*;

  public class AnimalHospital {

     public AnimalHospital(String inputFile) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(inputFile));  
       // how do I get input, into printPetInfoByName()? 

     }

     public void printPetInfoByName(String petName){
       // this is only here to show you that I need input in order for 
       // the program to work

          String pName = "";
          String oName = "";
          String color = "";
          String hLength = "" ; // for cat only
          String size = ""; // dog only
          String dog = "";
          String bird = "";
      /* This is how my file looks that is being read in
           CAT
           Ginger Owen Brown female medium
           CAT
           Busker Samantha male short*/

          while(!(input.next().equals("END"))) {

               if(input.next().equals("CAT")) {
                    pName = input.next();  // searching for inserted name
                    if(pName.equals(petName)) { // if found
                         oName = input.next();
                         color = input.next();
                         hLength = input.next();
                         Cat cat = new Cat(pName, oName,color, hLength);
                     // have to grab every word in the line to get each variable
                         cat.toString();
                    }
                }
                if(input.nextLine().equals("DOG")){
                    pName = input.next();
                    if(pName.equals(petName)) {
                         oName = input.next();
                         color = input.next();
                         size = input.next();
                         Dog d = new Dog(pName, oName, color, size);
                         // have to grab every word in the line to get each variable
                        d.toString();
                    }
                }
                if(input.nextLine().equals("BIRD")){
                    pName = input.next();
                    if(pName.equals(petName)){
                        oName = input.next();
                        color = input.next();
                        //size = input.next();
                         Bird b = new Bird(pName, oName, color);
                         //have to grab every word in the line to get each variable
                         b.toString();
                    }
                }/*else{
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Pet Not Found." );
                }*/

           }
       }
```

here is my tester:

```
  public class Tester {

      public static void main (String[]args)throws FileNotFoundException {

            AnimalHospital a = new AnimalHospital("data.txt");
            a.printPetInfoByName("Ginger");

      } 
  }
```

I feel as though this is a very simple issue, yet I have no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Possibly you are meant to pass the Scanner as a method parameter to those additional methods.  Some additional code would help.

Comment: Well, you cant use `input` because its **scope** is the constructor.

Comment: Without declaring an instance variable this is impossible to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using a variable in constructor in a method outside of constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500170/using-a-variable-in-constructor-in-a-method-outside-of-constructor)

Comment: Perhaps you are understanding your assignment incorrectly?

Comment: I went ahead and added a variable like private Scanner input; at the top, but now Im having issues with my while loop when I run it from my tester. I get a nullPointerException on the line where my while loop begins.

Answer (score 0):

As Alexander alluded to in the comments, you cannot use the scanner while its scope does not reach outside of the constructor. If the only requirement is that you pass the *text* file in the constructor, then you simply need to declare the scanner in the AnimalHospital class and initialize it within the constructor like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class AnimalHospital{
    Scanner input;

    public AnimalHospital(String inputFile)throws FileNotFoundException{

        input = new Scanner(new File(inputFile));  
   // how do I get input, into printPetInfoByName()? 

    }

    public void printPetInfoByName(String petName){
    // this is only here to show you that I need input in order for 
    // the program to work
        String pName = "";
        String oName = "";
        String color = "";
        String hLength = "" ; // for cat only
        String size = ""; // dog only
        String dog = "";
        String bird = "";
    /* This is how my file looks that is being read in
       CAT
       Ginger Owen Brown female medium
       CAT
       Busker Samantha male short*/

  while(!(input.next().equals("END"))){

       if(input.next().equals("CAT")){
            pName = input.next();  // searching for inserted name
            if(pName.equals(petName)){ // if found
                 oName = input.next();
                 color = input.next();
                 hLength = input.next();
                 Cat cat = new Cat(pName, oName,color, hLength);
                 // have to grab every word in the line to get each variable
                 cat.toString();
            }

        }
        if(input.nextLine().equals("DOG")){
            pName = input.next();
            if(pName.equals(petName)){
                 oName = input.next();
                 color = input.next();
                 size = input.next();
                 Dog d = new Dog(pName, oName, color, size);
                 // have to grab every word in the line to get each variable
                 d.toString();
            }
        }
        if(input.nextLine().equals("BIRD")){
            pName = input.next();
            if(pName.equals(petName)){
                 oName = input.next();
                 color = input.next();
                // size = input.next();
                 Bird b = new Bird(pName, oName, color);
                 // have to grab every word in the line to get each variable
                 b.toString();
            }
        }/*else{
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Pet Not Found." );
            }*/


   }
}
```

As a side note, I think you forgot to define a variable for the gender, since I noticed you had "female" in your example input.