# Java eclipse: can not be resolved as a variable

Tags: java, eclipse

Thanks for help in advance. I am a beginner of Java.  I am using a class and defines its constructors. The 1st version is wrong with comments inside the code:

```
public class QueueByStacks {
    // constructor
    public QueueByStacks() {
        LinkedList<Integer> in = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        LinkedList<Integer> out = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    }

    public Integer poll() {
        move();
        return isEmpty()? null : out.pollFirst();
        // out can not be resolved. But I think out is defined in the constructor then when I call the constructor in the main function then it should be initialized, so why I can not use out here?
    }
}
```

I modified the code and it works:

```
public class QueueByStacks {    
    private LinkedList<Integer> in;
    private LinkedList<Integer> out;
    // constructor
    public QueueByStacks() {
        in = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        out = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    }
}
```

So I am wondering why the 1st version is wrong? My understanding is that when I call a class actually I am calling the constructor so "in" and "out" should be able to be used across the methods. I appreciate any helps. Thanks.

Comment: the 1st version, in/out are local variable, and its lifecycle is just in constructor method.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the right post to answer my question. In summary, in my 1st version, "in" and "out" are local variable and they only exist during the execution of constructor.

[using a variable in constructor in a method outside of constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500170/using-a-variable-in-constructor-in-a-method-outside-of-constructor)